# Send values from one component to the other

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular material paginator: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples
The paginator triggers an event and I print the page size and a page index. 
I have this method in let say Component A.

```
 paginate($event: PageEvent) {
    concole.log($event.pageIndex);
    console.log($event.pageSize);  
  }
```

In Component B, I have two variables `pIndex` and `pSize`.

I want to assign these variables with values that I get from the PageEvent.

But the pageEvent happens in Component A.

I tried to add an event emitter in component A to emit the page size.

```
export class ComponentA {

    @Output() pageSizeEmitter = new EventEmitter<number>();

    paginate($event: PageEvent) {
      this.pageSizeEmitter.emit($event.pageSize);
      concole.log($event.pageIndex);
      console.log($event.pageSize);
    }
}
```

But then in Component B, I don't know how to assign it to the `pSize` variable.

```
export class ComponentB {

    pIndex: number =0; 
    pSize: number =?

}
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do that. One way is (maybe the simplest at the stage you are with your code - see the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma613768926433166)):

```html
<component-b #compB></component-b>

<component-a (pageSizeEmitter)="compB.pSize = $event"></component-a>
```

Basically we are using template reference variables (`compB` in the code above).

You can improve that code significantly by calling a function and passing, as arguments, `compB` and `$event` and doing the rest on ts code.

And be warned that an `*ngIf` on `<component-b>` would ruin this solution. So, if I were you, I'd use more typescript code:

```js
@ViewChild('compB') _compB: ComponentBComponent;

_setPageSize(pageSize: number) {this._compB.pSize = pageSize;}
```

```html
<component-b #compB></component-b>

<component-a (pageSizeEmitter)="_setPageSize($event)"></component-a>
```

But, if I was doing it in production code, I'd do it using services, or, even better, using a complete state management solution, like ngrx.

Comment: can you make sample in stackbliz?

Comment: Of course. I'll put it in the answer. I simplified somethings two make it easier to build the stackblitz.